# Form Input (Array) as PUT request in Python

Tags: python, arrays, put

I'm trying to replicate a PUT request using Python3.  The Form Data I need to send looks like this in Firefox:

[image: p]

And like this in Chrome:

[image]

I've tried the following:

```
explanation_data = user_a1.put(
    f"/review/{card_id}/verify", f"answerIds%5B%5D={answer1_id}&answerIds%5B%5D={answer2_id}"
)

explanation_data = user_a1.put(
    f"/review/{card_id}/verify", {
        "answerIds":[answer1_id],
        "answerIds":[answer2_id]
    }
)

explanation_data = user_a1.put(
    f"/review/{card_id}/verify", {
        "answerIds":[answer1_id,answer2_id]
    }
)

explanation_data = user_a1.put(
    f"/review/{card_id}/verify", {
        "answerIds":[answer1_id],
        "answerIds":[answer2_id]
    }
)
```

And other permutations, to no avail.  When the question has a single answer (like below):
[image]

Then the following code functions perfectly:

```
        explanation_data = user_a1.put(
            f"/review/{card_id}/verify", {
                "answerIds":[answer2_id]
            }
        )
```

I'm sure it's something very obvious.  Where am I going wrong?

Comment: are you using requests or what framework to make the HTTP call?

Comment: `requests>=2.22,<2.23`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `requests==2.6.2`, below is the sample python code to make PUT request with your desire URL.

```
import requests

headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
url = "http://localhost:5000"
params = (
    ('answerIds', ['1234', '5678']),
)

req = requests.put(url, params=params, headers=headers)
print req.status
```

When I am printing URL for above request server side. Below is the output.

```
http://localhost:5000/?answerIds=1234&answerIds=5678
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: in the end it turned out there was some custom logic inside that "put" function, I fixed it in the end, this answer didn't contribute but I'd say that it helped insofar as I realised it was nothing to do with the 'requests' library specifically